# Logarithms with same base, do signs change when you drop the base and solve?

Tags: logarithms, quadratics

$$e^{x^2}=e^{18x} \cdot 1/e^{80}$$

I dropped the e since it was the same base and solved:

$$x^2=18x-80$$

I then moved $ 18x$ and $80$ to the other side and got:
$$x^2-18x+80=0$$

The roots are $ 8 $ and $ 10 $ but its not possible with the signs I got. Where did I go wrong with the signs?

Thank you

Sorry, this is the final form of what I meant. I am new here

Comment: Please use TEX. Your equations are not legible.

Comment: Why is it not possible; what is the problem with the signs...?

Comment: I don't see the problem here.

Comment: Please don't silently change the question as this makes the comments absurd.

Comment: The sign of $80$ is wrong.

Comment: I think this was a typo, so I've corrected it.

Comment: should it be -80 once 1/e80 is flipped?

Comment: @RayRuiz: See the answer. Any other doubt?

Answer (score 2):

$$e^{x^2}=e^{18x} \cdot 1/e^{80} \Rightarrow x^2=18x+(-80) \Rightarrow x^2-18x+80=0$$
what give us $x=10$ or $x=8$

Answer (score 1):

Okey, there are a couple of mistakes on your procedure:
$$e^{18x}/e^{80}=e^{(18x-80)}$$,
so, when you "drop the $e$", that is to say, when you take the logarhythm of both sides, you have:
$$x^2=18x-80$$.
Then you only have to be carefull with your rearrangement of the equation.